# SQL query showing different record count than PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm new to PHP and am not sure how to troubleshoot this...if I look at my projects table in phpMyAdmin, it has 720 records in it. If I then run this code, it echos 273 records.

```
$sql_cnt = "SELECT project_id FROM projects";
if ($result_count = $conn->query($sql_cnt)) {
    echo ('Projects table has ' . $result_count->num_rows . ' records in it.<br>');
    $result_count->close();
}
```

I've read that phpMyAdmin may not give an exact record count, but it seems a lot closer to what I would expect vs. the PHP code. The table has an autonumber id field, and I've tried using that instead of project_id (which is an external system's id, but both fields should be all unique values), but I had the same results. Is this an issue with my PHP?

Comment: Are there NULL values on rows for that column?

Comment: Just double checked--no null values in either id column.

Comment: Are you connecting to the same DB ?

Comment: Yes, same DB (though great thought).

Comment: Are there any rows that don't contain value?

Comment: Seeing a comment of yours below, you could also use a GROUP BY if DISTINCT doesn't work. Sometimes even a combination of both in rare cases.

Comment: Thanks for all the good input. I'd love to know why somebody would vote down this question--seems to me if it's soliciting discussion and you choose to vote it down, you should have to leave a comment explaining that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try to 'distinct' the project_id ?

```
Select distinct project_id from projects;
```

Comment: For comments, add a comment. Is this an actual answer?

Comment: That actually did seem to work, though there were no duplicate values in the ID columns--am I misunderstanding the distinct function? Also, if I follow up my count with a move (`INSERT INTO projects_prev SELECT * FROM projects`), do I need to do something similar (like maybe `INSERT INTO projects_prev SELECT DISTINCT * FROM projects`)? Thanks!

Comment: btw, how do u insert your record ??